# Compare two Linq objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I wanna compare two identical Linq table objects iterating through theirs properties but I have to omit some properties, which are generic type with one parameter e.g. EntitySet (LinqTable has many different types), how could I check if property is that type (EntitySet)?

Sorry for no code, but I write from mobile phone :) I will append some code if it will be necessary ;)

EDIT:

I finally solve that problem with code below:

```
internal static void AssertIsEqualTo<T>(this T value, T comparedValue, List<string> fieldsToAvoid)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

    if (fieldsToAvoid == null)
    {
        fieldsToAvoid = new List<string>();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
    {
        var expectedPropertyValue = properties[i].GetValue(value, null);
        var actualPropertyValue = properties[i].GetValue(comparedValue, null);

        if (!fieldsToAvoid.Contains(properties[i].Name))
        {
            if (properties[i].PropertyType.Name != typeof(System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<object>).Name)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(expectedPropertyValue, actualPropertyValue, "In {0} object {1} is not equal.", type.ToString(), properties[i].Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Name Property of Type object is something like "EntitySet '1" which means EntitySet object with one parameter.

Maybe someone knows better way to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that implements IEqualityComparer e.g.

```
public class ProjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<Project>
{
    public bool Equals(Project x, Project y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;
        else
            return (x.ProjectID == y.ProjectID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Project obj)
    {
        return obj.ProjectID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Replace the logic in the Equals method with whatever you need, then use to compare your objects in one of various ways e.g. most simply:

```
bool areEqual = new ProjectComparer().Equals(project1, project2);
```